# Ajax request 500 error - Call to a member fucntion on null

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have my Ajax. method within Symfony which sends id of the clicked button in specific table row.

My error log returns:

> Call to a member function changeStatus() on null

This is strange, because when I **dump($id)** in my Controller, it's shows the id of that entity object, so I can not figure out where the problem is.

This is my method:

```
/**
  * @Route("/my-entity-route/{id}", name="change_status", options={"expose"=true})
  */
    public function changeStatus($id)
    {
       // dump($id);die; -- shows id number

        $entity = $this->entityManager->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($id);

        $entity->setStatus(MyEntity::STATUS_CHANGE);
        $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    
    }
}
```

And my button:

```
<button type="button" data-entity_id="{{ item.id }}" class="change">Switch Status</button>
```

And method in js file:

```
$(".change").click(function(ev, el){
var id = $(this).data("entity_id");
if (confirm("Are you sure that you want change status?")) {
    changeToNewStatus(id);
 }
});

function changeToNewStatus(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PATCH',
        url: "/my-entity-route/"+id,
        processData: false,
        contentType: 'application/json-patch+json',
        success: function () {
            console.log('success!')
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            alert(err.message);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Can you add to the post the file where you use `changeStatus` method ?

Comment: Thank you for replay. Can you explain why is that relevant? Other methods from the file work as excepted. @Mcsky

Comment: In what file and on which line does the error appear?

Comment: What's the result of dump($entity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the entity you try to get from database don't exists, are you sure that you request an existing entity with the right id?

Also, it's best to fire a 404 instead of getting a null pointer:

```php
/**
  * @Route("/my-entity-route/{id}", name="change_status", options={"expose"=true})
  */
    public function changeStatus($id)
    {
        $entity = $this->entityManager->getRepository(MyEntity::class)->find($id);
        if (!$entity) {
             throw $this->createNotFoundException('The entity does not exist');
        }

        $entity->setStatus(MyEntity::STATUS_CHANGE);
        $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```